Derivative of a matrix w.r.t a scalar
I have a notation in the Frobenius form, which is denoted as
$\||\mathbf{Y}-\alpha\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}\||_F^2$.
I want to find the derivative of the scalar $\alpha$ and update this parameter with gradient descent method, but when I looked up the data, I found that the derivative of the scalar matrix is still the size of the matrix. If there is some way to get the gradient in the form of a scalar?

"I want to find the derivative of the scalar $\alpha$",  zero?

According to the matrix-scalar derivative rule, the derivative of the scalar $\alpha$ of this equation should be a matrix size?

If I understand correctly you have a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f(\alpha) = \lVert \mathbf{Y} - \alpha \mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} \rVert_F^2$$
and you want to compute $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\alpha} f$. By definition of the Frobenius norm,
\begin{align*}
f(\alpha) &= \mathsf{Tr}\left( \left( \mathbf{Y} - \alpha \mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} \right) \left( \mathbf{Y} - \alpha \mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} \right)^\top \right) \\
&= \mathsf{Tr}\left( \mathbf{Y} \mathbf{Y}^\top - \alpha  \mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{Y}^\top - \alpha \mathbf{Y} \mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{A}^\top + \alpha^2 \mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{A}^\top \right) \\
&= \mathsf{Tr}\left( \mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^\top \right) - \alpha \mathsf{Tr}\left( \mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{Y}^\top \right) - \alpha \mathsf{Tr}\left( \mathbf{Y} \mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{A}^\top \right) + \alpha^2 \mathsf{Tr}\left( \mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{A}^\top \right) \\
&= \mathsf{Tr}\left( \mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}^\top \right) - 2 \alpha \mathsf{Tr}\left( \mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{Y}^\top \right) + \alpha^2 \mathsf{Tr}\left( \mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{A}^\top \right)
\end{align*}
It's then clear
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\alpha}f = 2 \alpha \mathsf{Tr}\left( \mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{A}^\top \right) - 2 \mathsf{Tr}\left( \mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{Y}^\top \right)$$
which will yield a scalar value.

Its worthwhile remarking that $f(\alpha)$ is a quadratic function with respect to $\alpha$, so the minimizer can be identified analytically.
